# Generate list of dependent packages with version using top level package from input file in Ubuntu or Debian

Tags: apt, dpkg, aptitude, apt-cache

Is there something like npm lock-file in Ubuntu/Debian which can generate the Debian package tree with exact versions for direct and transitive dependencies? For example, a lock-file for Redis will be something like

```
redis-server= 5:4.0.9-1ubuntu0.2
lsb-base=3.2-14
redis-tools=5:4.0.9-1ubuntu0.2
lsb-base
libc6= 2.14
 ...
```

Also, if such a state can be generated programmatically then how to use it for apt-get install or dpkg?

Comment: The complete Debian package tree would run to hundreds (sometimes thousands) of packages. Perhaps you mean *a list dependencies that are not already installed?* That's easy: `sudo apt install <package_name> --simulate`

Comment: that's correct. the requirement is to version control the host state instead of randomly installing from ubuntu mirrors which creates configuration drift over time. Planning to generate host state (package lists with direct & transitive dependencies) using input file which would have only top level packages.